# Python pong game using turtle graphics, issue with pen.clear() and ball slowdown

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I'm following this pong tutorial using turtle graphics, after adding the "Pen" section, for some reason the ball started moving very slowly, adjusting the speed (ball.dx/ball.dy) to 0.2 or 2.0 makes no difference, but, more importantly, the pen.clear() is not doing its job when the ball crosses the border.  What am I missing?

```
# simple pong for beginners

import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong by Flameo")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=1000, height=1000) 
wn.tracer(0)

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1 )
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-450, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1 )
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(+450, 0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("red")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2

# function

def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 40
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 40
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y += 40
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y -= 40
    paddle_b.sety(y)

# keyboard binding

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "i")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "k")
# main game loop

while True:
    wn.update()
    
    # move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 490:
        ball.sety(490)
        ball.dy *= -1
    if ball.ycor() < -490:
        ball.sety(-490)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 490:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Humans: {} Aliens: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align ="center", font=("Courier", 30, "normal"))
        
    
    if ball.xcor() < -490:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Humans: {} Aliens: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align ="center", font=("Courier", 30, "normal"))

    # paddle and ball collisions

    if ball.xcor() > 440 and ball.xcor() < 450 and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -50):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -440 and ball.xcor() > -450 and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -50):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    # Pen

    pen = turtle.Turtle()
    pen.speed(0)
    pen.color("white")
    pen.penup()
    pen.hideturtle()
    pen.goto(0, 450)
    pen.write("Humans: 0 Aliens: 0", align ="center", font=("Courier", 30, "normal"))
```

The pen.clear() is supposed to reset the scoreboard and replace 0 with 1 everytime the ball goes outside the border, but it doesn't.

```
if ball.xcor() < -490:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Humans: {} Aliens: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align ="center", font=("Courier", 30, "normal"))
```

Comment: You're creating a brand-new `pen` turtle on every iteration of your loop.  Calling `.clear()` on it only removes text drawn with the most recent version of it, anything drawn by previous iterations is permanent because you have no reference to the turtle.

Comment: Ha! Much appreciated! Moving the #Pen section to right after the #Ball solved both issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Below full working code for the Pong game provided in order to get this question marked as answered:

```
# simple pong for beginners

import turtle
from time import sleep

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong by Flameo")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=1000, height=1000) 
wn.tracer(0)

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 450)
pen.write("Humans: 0 Aliens: 0", align ="center", font=("Courier", 30, "normal"))

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1 )
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-450, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1 )
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(+450, 0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("circle")
ball.color("red")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2

# event handling functions
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 40
    paddle_a.sety(y)
def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 40
    paddle_a.sety(y)
def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y += 40
    paddle_b.sety(y)
def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y -= 40
    paddle_b.sety(y)

# keyboard bindings
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "i")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "k")

# main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()
    sleep(0.02)
    
    # move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 490:
        ball.sety(490)
        ball.dy *= -1
    if ball.ycor() < -490:
        ball.sety(-490)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 490:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Humans: {} Aliens: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align ="center", font=("Courier", 30, "normal"))
        
    
    if ball.xcor() < -490:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Humans: {} Aliens: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align ="center", font=("Courier", 30, "normal"))

    # paddle and ball collisions

    if ball.xcor() > 440 and ball.xcor() < 450 and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -50):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -440 and ball.xcor() > -450 and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -50):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1
```